# HTML form posting

Tags: html

I have studied that when making a form using HTML , you want to create a Text Field , you use the following code :

```
<Input type="text" name = "-Name_of_Text_Field-">
```

So this will create a text box on the web page whose value will be stored in whatever name of the text field that you have specified , right ?

My question is , we know that a variable is a named memory location . So where actually is this location ? Is it on the web page itself or where ?

I haven't been taught this at my school and am very interested to learn more .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code `<Input type="text" name = "-Name_of_Text_Field-">` will create a text input box. But there is no variable created. Typically what happens is that you use a server side script, like PHP, to pull the value when the form is submitted.

Comment: Ok , so Server side scripting is being done ? I didn't know that sir .

Thanks . 

Also can you refer to me some sources from where I can learn Dynamic HTML ? Thanks again sir :)